# Magento2: Live Page 500 Server Error

Tags: magento2, server-setup

I have a page that is enabled and still is giving me a 500 error. https://case-mate.com/iridescent-wristlet-folio-iphone7 is a live product. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at your web server error log file?
What does it says?

Comment: Also, a search doesn't show that item, but there is this item - https://case-mate.com/iridescent-wristlet-folio-iphone6 - which is also 500

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general and the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. If you are running apache check here for the error log:

```
/var/log/apache2/
```

You can also enable error display at *app/bootstrap.php*

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1)
```